# Android Gridview height=fillparent or wrapcontent is not working

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi I am trying to create a yearly calendar which uses a gridview and inner gridview. The main grid view used to hold 12 item for months.And innergridview used to hold date.The xml file for main grid view and inner grid view is shown below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/inner_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<include
    android:id="@+id/include1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    layout="@layout/sample" />

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridv_all_months"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/include2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/include1"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:numColumns="3"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp" >
</GridView>

<include
    android:id="@+id/include2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/include3"
    layout="@layout/attendance_foot_bar" />

<include
    android:id="@+id/include3"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    layout="@layout/logo_footer" />
```

//

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_month"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textv_month_name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="7dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/top_bar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textv_month_name"
        android:background="@drawable/calendar_top_small"
        android:clickable="false" />

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridv_inner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/top_bar"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="7"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >
    </GridView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/monthBtn"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

when I try this way all rows of  inner gridview will come.If i changed

```
android:layout_height="80dp"
```

to

```
android:layout_height="fill parent"
```

Then inner gridview show only one row,so kindly help to find out the problem.Any help will be appreciable.

Comment: Try changing the first to fill_parent as well.

Comment: that's not the problem i already tried that way.

Comment: Did you actually leave out the underscore in `android:layout_height="fill parent"`?